# Is there an efficient way to find the principal curvatures?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, differential-geometry

Let $S$ be the surface $z=1+x^2+y^2.$ This is a regular surface with coordinate function  $\textbf{x}(u,v)=(u,v,1+u^2+v^2).$ The Gauss map $N:S \to S^2$  ($S^2$ is a sphere) is given by $(N \circ\textbf{x})(u,v)= \dfrac{(-2u,-2v,1)}{R}$ and $[-dN]_{B,B}=  \dfrac{2}{R^3}\begin{pmatrix}
4v^2+1 & -4uv \\
-4uv & 4u^2+1
\end{pmatrix},$ where  $R=\sqrt{1+4u^2+4v^2}$ and $B=\{\textbf{x}_u, \textbf{x}_v\}.$

Suppose $u,v \neq 0$. To find the principal curvatures, we need to solve for this characteristic equation:

$\text{det}([-dN]_{B,B} -k\textbf{I}_2)= 0 \Leftrightarrow \left(\dfrac{8v^2}{R^3}+\dfrac{2}{R^3}-k\right)\left(\dfrac{8u^2}{R^3}+\dfrac{2}{R^3}-k\right)-\dfrac{64u^2v^2}{R^6}=0.$

Clearly, one of the values of $k$ is $\dfrac{2}{R^3}.$ How do I find the other value of $k$ without using the quadratic formula ( which is too complicated) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you know one root of a quadratic equation,
the other one follows directly from the relation between roots and coefficients:
$k_2 = a-k_1$ (or $k_2=b/k_1$ if that's easier), if the equation is $k^2-ak+b=0$.